# Formatting Phone number with +1 with pandas.Series.replace

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I can't find a solution online and I know this should be easy but I can't figure out what is wrong with my regex:

here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company phone number': ['+1-541-296-2271', '+1-542-296-2271', '+1-543-296-2271'],
                   'Contact phone number': ['15112962271', None,'15312962271'],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2,3]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog','cat'])

df['Contact phone number'] = df['Contact phone number'].str.replace('^\d{11}$', r'\+1-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
```

desired output of `df['Contact phone number']`:

```
falcon    +1-511-296-2271
dog       None
cat       +1-531-296-2271
```

It is always 11 digits with no spaces or special characters.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
 df['Contact phone number'] = df['Contact phone number'].str.replace(r'^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$', r'+1-\1-\2-\3-\4', regex=True)
```

*Details*:

- `^` - a start of string
- `(\d)` - Group 1 (`\1`): a digit
- `(\d{3})` - Group 2 (`\2`): three digits
- `(\d{3})` - Group 3 (`\3`): three digits
- `(\d+)` - Group 4 (`\4`): any one or more digits (use `\d{4}` if you need to match exactly four next digits)
- `$` - end of string.

Output:

```
>>> df['Contact phone number']
falcon    +1-1-511-296-2271
dog                    None
cat       +1-1-531-296-2271
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t83z4F/1).

Comment: Wow, this is a lot better than my answer. Surprised I didn't think of using `replace`! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str.extract`, convert each row of results to a list, and then use `.str.join` (and of course concatenate a `+` at the beginning):

```
df['Contact phone number'] = '+' + df['Contact phone number'].dropna().astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})').apply(list, axis=1).str.join('-')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       Company phone number Contact phone number  num_specimen_seen
falcon      +1-541-296-2271       +1-511-296-227                 10
dog         +1-542-296-2271                  NaN                  2
cat         +1-543-296-2271       +1-531-296-227                  3
```

Comment: Thanks @richardec! With the dropna() shouldn't that drop the row with the None in it or does it just have the effect of converting None to NaN?

Comment: `dropna` treats `None` and `NaN` identically; the reason the `NaN` is there instead of `None` is because `NaN` is what pandas fills in empty spots.